How to rename a device based on USB slot with Debian Linux?
I am using Debian 12 and I have two identical Huawei E3372-325 modems connected to my computer.
My goal is to assign each modem a human-readable, persistent name.
Unfortunately, both the name and MAC address of the modems change every time they are plugged in. Therefore, the only reliable way to identify them is by the port they're connected to.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Identify the current names using ip link show: enx46d33b6fafe7
Find device details with udevadm:
sudo udevadm test /sys/class/net/enx46d33b6fafe7

From the output, I found:
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0

Add a udev rule:
I added the following line to /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules:
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0", NAME="ltm_modem_1"

Apply the new udev rule:
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger
sudo udevadm trigger --action=add /sys/class/net/enx46d33b6fafe7

Unfortunately, this approach did not work. When I check with ip link show, the modem still retains its old name.


Apply the new udev rule:
[...]
When I check with ip link show, the modem still retains its old name.

Interfaces cannot be renamed when they're <UP>. You need to bring it down using ip link set enxXX down or unplug/reconnect the device.
(It seems this restriction was lifted with kernel 6.2, but your Debian most likely is still running version 6.1.)

Creating a custom /etc/systemd/network/*.link file (which will then be applied by udev's 80-net-setup-link.rules) is a slightly newer way of achieving this – although directly renaming via udev .rules continues to be supported (indeed .link files use the same mechanism), certain things can be more convenient through .link config files.
Additionally, path-based names (though not entirely human-readable) are already the systemd default, and normally /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link would result in a name such as enp0s3u1 for a USB device.
It's specifically Debian which switches USB network interfaces to MAC-based names via /usr/lib/systemd/network/73-usb-net-by-mac.link (or a custom udev rule in Debian 11), mostly due to people having the opposite problem when it comes to real Ethernet dongles.

Thanks, that worked great! I created a a file called "/etc/systemd/network/10-ltm-modem-1.link", added [Match]
Path=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0
[Link]
Name=ltm-modem-1 and then restarted. Worked perfectly!

In Xubuntu, which is based on Debian, I make such changes:
(all commands as root)
in the file /etc/default/grub line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
change to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0"
then sudo update-grub
and restarting the laptop.
